# Mahout Recomendaton engine recommending products and with its Quantity to customer

Tags: mahout, recommendation-engine, mahout-recommender

i am working on mahout recommendation engine use case.I precomputed recommendations and stored in database. now i am planning to expose with taste rest services to .net.i had limited customers and products.it is distributor level recommendation use case.my question is if new distributor comes in ,how would i suggests recommendations to him.and also how would i suggest the Quantity of Recommended product to each distributor.could you people give me some guidance.am i going to face performance issues..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is, when new user comes, to precompute the recommendations from scratch for all the users or only for this user. You should know that this user might change the recommendations for the others too. Its up to your needs frequently do you want to do the pre-computations.

However, if you have limited number of users and items, another way is to have online recommender that computes the recommendations in real time. If you use the `FileDataModel`, there is a way to get the data from the new user periodically (See the book [Mahout in Action](http://www.manning.com/owen/)). If you use in memory data model, which is faster, you can override the methods: `setPreference(long userID, long itemID, float value)` and `removePreference(long userID, long itemID)`, and whenever new user comes and likes or removes some items you should call these methods on your data model.

**EDIT**: Basically you can get the `GenericDataModel`, and add this to the methods `setPreference` and `removePreference`. This will be your lower level data model. You can wrap it afterwards with `ReloadFromJDBCDataModel` by setting your data model in the `reload()` method like this:

> DataModel newDelegateInMemory =
>                 delegate.hasPreferenceValues()
>                 ? new MutableDataModel(delegate.exportWithPrefs())
>                 : new MutableBooleanPrefDataModel(delegate.exportWithIDsOnly());

The overridden methods:

```
@Override
public void setPreference(long userID, long itemID, float value) {

    userIDs.add(userID);
    itemIDs.add(itemID);

    setMinPreference(Math.min(getMinPreference(), value));
    setMaxPreference(Math.max(getMaxPreference(), value));

    Preference p = new GenericPreference(userID, itemID, value);

    // User preferences
    GenericUserPreferenceArray newUPref;
    int existingPosition = -1;
    if (preferenceFromUsers.containsKey(userID)) {
        PreferenceArray oldPref = preferenceFromUsers.get(userID);
        newUPref = new GenericUserPreferenceArray(oldPref.length() + 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < oldPref.length(); i++) {
            //If the item does not exist in the liked user items, add it!
            if(oldPref.get(i).getItemID()!=itemID){
                newUPref.set(i, oldPref.get(i));
            }else{
                //Otherwise remember the position
                existingPosition = i;
            }
        }
        if(existingPosition>-1){
            //And change the preference value
            oldPref.set(existingPosition, p);
        }else{
            newUPref.set(oldPref.length(), p);
        }
    } else {
        newUPref = new GenericUserPreferenceArray(1);
        newUPref.set(0, p);
    }
    if(existingPosition == -1){
        preferenceFromUsers.put(userID, newUPref);
    }

    // Item preferences
    GenericItemPreferenceArray newIPref;
    existingPosition = -1;
    if (preferenceForItems.containsKey(itemID)) {
        PreferenceArray oldPref = preferenceForItems.get(itemID);
        newIPref = new GenericItemPreferenceArray(oldPref.length() + 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < oldPref.length(); i++) {
            if(oldPref.get(i).getUserID()!=userID){
                newIPref.set(i, oldPref.get(i));
            }else{
                existingPosition = i;
            }
        }
        if(existingPosition>-1){
            oldPref.set(existingPosition, p);
        }else{
            newIPref.set(oldPref.length(), p);
        }
    } else {
        newIPref = new GenericItemPreferenceArray(1);
        newIPref.set(0, p);
    }
    if(existingPosition == -1){
        preferenceForItems.put(itemID, newIPref);
    }   
}

@Override
public void removePreference(long userID, long itemID) {
    // User preferences
    if (preferenceFromUsers.containsKey(userID)) {
        List<Preference> newPu = new ArrayList<Preference>();
        for (Preference p : preferenceFromUsers.get(userID)) {
            if(p.getItemID()!=itemID){
                newPu.add(p);
            }       
        }
        preferenceFromUsers.remove(userID);
        preferenceFromUsers.put(userID, new GenericUserPreferenceArray(newPu)); 
    }
    if(preferenceFromUsers.get(userID).length()==0){
        preferenceFromUsers.remove(userID);
        userIDs.remove(userID); 
    }
    if (preferenceForItems.containsKey(itemID)) {
        List<Preference> newPi = new ArrayList<Preference>();
        for (Preference p : preferenceForItems.get(itemID)) {
            if(p.getUserID() != userID){
                newPi.add(p);
            }   
        }
        preferenceForItems.remove(itemID);
        preferenceForItems.put(itemID, new GenericItemPreferenceArray(newPi));
    }   
    if(preferenceForItems.get(itemID).length()==0){
        //Not sure if this is needed, but it works without removing the item
        //preferenceForItems.remove(itemID);
        //itemIDs.remove(itemID);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks Dragan,currently i am trying to develop Real time recommendation engine with Rest.I am planning to use Memory data model.can you please share your implemented one for my reference.

Answer (score 0):

If by "new distributor" you mean that you have no data for them, no historical data. Then you cannot make recommendations using Mahout's recommenders.

You can suggest other items once they chose one. Use Mahout's "itemsimilarity" driver to calculate similar items for everything in your catalog. Then if they choose something you can suggest similar items.

The items that come from the itemsimilarity driver can be stored in you DB as a column value containing ids for similar items for every item. Then you can index the column with a search engine and use the user's first order as the query. This will return realtime personalized recommendations and is the most up-to-date method suggested by the Mahout people.

See a description of how to do this in this book by Ted Dunning, one of the leading Mahout Data Scientists. http://www.mapr.com/practical-machine-learning

Comment: thanks for suggestion.I got your point.my other doubt is i am trying to implement with Java ,web services.i am not using search engine (solr). I need to expose Recommendation engine to .Net cross platform with REST. my technologies are Mysql,Java Web services,Mahout. am i going in right direction,or i miss any thing.